# Vagrant up returning "Compressed image is corrupted"

Tags: vagrant

I'm trying to create a vagrant box using Ubuntu 14.04 32bit as a base.

The first VMDK was packaged and tested successfully. Then I realized it takes too long to provision the box with Latex (Tex Live). So I created a new package in the following manner:

1. Created "full clone" of the original VMDK (Checked "Reinitialize the MAC address of all network cards")
2. Installed Latex.
3. Shutdown and started packaging the clone.

Once I added the package to vagrant, I created a new vagrant box. But running it returned the following:

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'ubuntu-latex'...
Progress: 10%There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["import", "/home/me/.vagrant.d/boxes/ubuntu-latex/0/virtualbox/box.ovf", "--vsys", "0", "--vmname", "Ubuntu-HL-Latex_1_1405303855841_84250", "--vsys", "0", "--unit", "11", "--disk", "/home/me/VirtualBox VMs/Ubuntu-HL-Latex_1_1405303855841_84250/box-disk2.vmdk"]

Stderr: 0%...10%...20%...30%...40%...50%...60%...70%...80%...90%...100%
Interpreting /home/me/.vagrant.d/boxes/ubuntu-latex/0/virtualbox/box.ovf...
OK.
0%...10%...
Progress state: VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR
VBoxManage: error: Appliance import failed
VBoxManage: error: Could not create the clone medium '/home/me/VirtualBox VMs/Ubuntu-HL-Latex_1_1405303855841_84250/box-disk2.vmdk'.
VBoxManage: error: VMDK: Compressed image is corrupted '/home/me/.vagrant.d/boxes/ubuntu-latex/0/virtualbox/box-disk2.vmdk' (VERR_ZIP_CORRUPTED)
VBoxManage: error: Details: code VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80bb0004), component Appliance, interface IAppliance
VBoxManage: error: Context: "int handleImportAppliance(HandlerArg*)" at line 779 of file VBoxManageAppliance.cpp
```

The vagrantfile was never changed after `vagrant init` was executed for both the original and latex boxes.

Would anyone have an idea on what's happening and how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I fixed it like that:

```
$vagrant box list

$vagrant box remove precise6

$vagrant up
```